# check if values in a column maps coherently into another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I copied the values from a file into one table of a database I created to query the data with sql language. Db is not in normal form, I just copied values into fields.

Indeed, first of all, I would check by queries if data I have are coherent in this sense: **at same values of field f1 corresponds, for every record, same values of f2**.

It can also happen that different values of f1 are associated with same values in f2, it is not a problem; and obviously if the check would be positive in both directions (f1 -> f2 and f2 -> f1) it would mean that the two fields are one-to-one.

Example 1

```
id |   f1   |   f2
1  |   a    |   x 
2  |   b    |   y     
3  |   a    |   x     
4  |   c    |   x
```

In this example 1 the query should answer me TRUE (or something similar) because at equals values of f1 corresponds equal values of f2.

Example 2

```
id |   f1   |   f2
1  |   a    |   x 
2  |   b    |   y     
3  |   a    |   z     
4  |   c    |   x
```

In this example 2 the query should answer me FALSE (or something similar) because at equals values of f1 corresponds different values of f2.

Example 3

```
id |   f1   |   f2
1  |   a    |   x 
2  |   b    |   y     
3  |   a    |   x     
4  |   c    |   z
```

In this example 3 the query should answer me TRUE in both the directions f1->f2 and f2->f1.

Thank you all guys for the help, I hope to have been clear enough and, of course, I apologize for my bad english.

Comment: It is not clear, at least not to me. `because at equals values of f1 corresponds equal values of f2.` for the first example, but there is no equal values at all in between f1 and f2 unless you are talking about DIFFERENT rows with same values for f1 and f2. Even then it is not clear if you want to return true for all data or just those specific rows. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for my bad explanation.
I try to do better:
request: answer TRUE (or equivalent) if and only if for every record in the table at same values in the field f1 corresponds same values in the field f2.

Example 2 is False because exists two records with same value in f1 but different value in f2.

Comment: What if you have this situation: `a|x; z|y; c|a; a|c` How to know whether the equivalence is between a and x or a and c ? If this doesn't matter you will have to check each line with all other lines, doing a cross join to validate one row to every other.

Comment: In your example the answer should be FALSE because there are (at least) two records with the same value in the field f1 that have different values in field f2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an union on select distinct the resuling rows are these that don't match

```
 select f1 from 
 ( select  distinct f1, f2 
     from my_table ) t1
 group by f1
 having count(*) >1
 union 
 select f2 from 
 ( select  distinct f1, f2 
     from my_table ) t2
 group by f2
 having count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this here. i count all rows and compare it with the SUM from row where f1 equal f2. it return TRUE or FALSE as string but you can change it to all 0,1

```
SELECT
  IF( count(id) = SUM(IF(f1=f2,1,0)), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') as result
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This seems wrong -- it is not a question of f1=f2, but whether the f2 values are all different for each f1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(MAX(ct) = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
    FROM (
        SELECT f1,
               COUNT(DISTINCT f2) AS ct  -- hoping for only 1
            FROM my_table
            GROUP BY f1
         ) AS c;
```